# Connect to Hive database tables using postgresql-fdw from postgresql server

Tags: postgresql, hive, postgres-fdw

Cant connect from postgresql server to hive databases on remote server.

Tried using the following queries but doenst work. Connection established but no response back from hive server.

```
--create extension postgres_fdw;
DROP USER MAPPING  IF EXISTS  FOR   CURRENT_USER  SERVER data_db;
drop server data_db;
create server data_db
foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw
options (host 'net.com' , port 'hiveport' , SSLMODE 'allow', dbname 'datah');

create user mapping for current_user
server data_db
options(user 'user', password 'password');

drop schema app;
create schema app;

import foreign schema public
from server data_db
into app;
```

The result was unknown expecting authentication request from the server (SQL state 08001).

I would like to be able to establish a connection to the hive database clusters using the fdw from postgresql to import selective data.

Thank you very much in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postgres_fdw is for connecting to other PostgreSQL instances.  Hive doesn't use the same wire protocol as PostgreSQL does, so surely postgres_fdw would not be expected to connect to it successfully.  Perhaps you can try https://github.com/youngwookim/hive-fdw-for-postgresql or https://sourceforge.net/projects/hadoopfdw/.